# .astype() not working for multiple columns?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to convert multiple columns (not continuous columns) to integer. Why doesn't it work?  The code in second row is int but the third is not. Does `.astype()` only work for one column at a time only?

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns = list('abcde'))
data.iloc[:,[0,3]].astype(int) # The result is int
data.iloc[:,[0,3]]=data.iloc[:,[0,3]].astype(int)  # data type not changing
```

Comment: Try this: `data[data.columns[[0,3]]] = data.iloc[:,[0,3]].astype(int)` ;-) `df.iloc[]` - might potentially be applied to set of rows (i.e. not to the whole column), so I guess that's the reason why Pandas dosn't want to change the dtype

Comment: It works.But why don't my code work?

Comment: looks like `astype` doesn't modify in place, even though it looks like it should - it takes a `copy` argument, but the copy argument doesn't look like it's actually used anywhere in the code - looks like it _always_ copies. so the second line returns a modified frame, but doesn't modify the frame itself - the third line writes it back into the frame.